# WCF Web Service on Windows Server 2012

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-server-2012

Ok, I'm trying to get a .net 4 WCF service up on Windows Server 2012 R2 installation.  I noticed the .svc mime type was missing, so I went about following these instructions-

https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/publishing-a-wcf-service-on-iis8/

The problem is when I get to step two the system.servicemodel namespace and all of it's options are missing from the drop down.

I'm figuring it has something to do with the .net install.  Anyone know the fix?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 4 try to use this:

```
System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ended up having to enable WCF services for http on IIS, it isn't on by default on windows server 2012.